# Post Wordpress Blogs to Tridion, any out of the box API/extension?

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service

We have a requirement where the client is already using WordPress for publishing their blogs and now they also want to publish the same content on Tridion CMS as components.

I want to know if there is already any extension available out of the box or created by someone?

Else, I am thinking to create a REST API (in Java Spring) using Core Service which I can expose to the WordPress team and then can invoke the same while creating/updating/deleting the blog which in turn reflect in Tridion.

There is an already a great article which focusses on publishing the content from Tridion to WordPress but we don't want that feature for now: (https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/wordpress.aspx)

Any help would be appreciated if there is no OOB extension available, do you see any issue with the approach I am planning to take?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing out of the box.

I believe that your proposed solution of creating some middle-ware which provides an API to WordPress and then uses Core Service to create content in Tridion is a good one.

Did you also think about consuming something that already exists from WordPress and would not require any additional effort from that team... The RSS/Atom feed? If you created something that could consume that, you could use it for other feeds in future (It may also be valuable to the wider community, if you wished to contribute it).

Comment: Here's a project I wrote a long time ago to create content from RSS: https://github.com/NunoLinhares/kickstart-tridion-environment/tree/master/ImportContentFromRss/trunk/ImportContentFromRss

Comment: +1 to consuming a feed from WordPress either into the CMS or in the Web Application. It makes sense to import the WordPress content if editors need to localize or re-use the content. The hardest parts will likely be the CRUD logic and DTAP (Dev, Test, Acceptance, and Production). I'd guess there's only _one_ WordPress account/instance--would updates there change all CMS environments?

Comment: You could also create an ECL connector to Wordpress, in which case you don't need to worry about synchronization at all... I guess it all depends on the use case(s) you have

Comment: All good ideas. I just want to add that if do end up writing a service that talks to the Core Service, do yourself a favor and write it in .NET. Talking WCF from Java can be a right pain :)